# What's the best way to sync folders across 03 or more webservers?

Tags: replication, high-availability, drbd, glusterfs, ceph

I have 03 servers and I want to sync some folders across them. I'm using DRBD + OCFS2 for a year or so, but it doesn't support more than 02 servers right now. I read about GlusterFS and CEPH, but there are a lot of bad reviews about them related to files being lost.

I need all the servers synchronized in real time, using an active-active-active layout. Does anyone have an idea on how to do this?

**EDIT:**

My scenario includes millions of small files (10KB or less), so I need something with a good performance in this case. When using large files, GlusterFS has a good performance, but it suffers when handling small files.

Comment: http://www.drbd.org/users-guide/s-three-nodes.html - but seriously, have you ever considered a simple NFS mount instead of a complex distributed replication setup?

Comment: How much high-availability do you *really* need? Is there anything wrong with an NFS server?

Comment: I'm using a 2-node DRBD cluster with a NFS mount, but I want 03 copies (without DRBD) because I experienced some random reboots on both servers simultaneously when using DRBD + OCFS2 and I don't know why.

Comment: I'd focus on the "random reboots" aspect more than the "shared filesystem" bit.

Comment: The reboots occurred when checkarray (RAID) were running. AFAIK, it's a bug with OCFS2 under heavy loads, but I can't confirm it. That's one of the reasons I want to test something new.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on source of your data.

If data you want to sync is generated somewhere else (developers workstation, etc) and only distributed to clients via those 3 servers, I would recommend to push the data to each of three servers via rsync, or some CI tool like Jenkins, keeping the files on local disks of each server.

If the data is generated and served by those three servers, then external data storage like NFS is the simplest way. But, that potentially increases costs due to need for HA (at least 2 servers for NFS). If you are bound to only 3 serves, choose GlusterFS in this case. Gluster uses local filesystem for storing files, so in a mirror mode you can easily turn off Gluster in the future with minimal downtime (cause files are stored on local fs of each server).

Comment: In this case, data is generated by the servers. I'll give GlusterFS a try. Thanks a lot.